# How to avoid hard-coding the Reference for a UserControl?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, reference

I'd like to know whether or not there is a dynamic way to avoid hard-coding the Reference for a UserControl or by "USING"?

```
<%@ Reference Control="~/UserControl.ascx" %>
using UserControl;
```

I'm seeking a way to dynamically add References to UserControls to the page from code behind.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945324/asp-net-dynamically-added-user-control-saving-values-after-postback may be this help you not only adding dynamically but also handling events of dynamic generated User Controls

Comment: Check this same question 

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/1945f9ce-8eb7-456a-8e1e-ae226bba6805/

Comment: unfortunately none of them answered my question. I want to avoid hard coding the referencing a UserControl.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Those references are used at compile-time, aren't they? Your code behind isn't invoked until runtime.

Comment: @bmm6o, I have added UserControls to the page dynamically, and referenced them using <%@ Reference Control="~/UserControl.ascx" %>, so far everything is OK, but I don't want to Reference them hard-coded. I want to make dynamic the referencing part also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, this should do what you want to do-

Default.aspx

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Dynamic User Control Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h1>Dynamic User Control Test</h1>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="UserControlPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl uc = Page.LoadControl("~/UserControl.ascx") as UserControl;

        if (uc != null)
        {
            UserControlPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(uc);
        }
    }
}
```

UserControl.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="UserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="UserControl" %>

<p>Here is some content inside the user control</p>
```

UserControl.ascx.cs (this isn't needed if the UserControl is static and contains no solution specific code)

```
using System;

public partial class UserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

This will only work with controls that are dynamically added to the page though.

Comment: hi, thanks for your detailed answer :) 

it's very strange that your referenceless solution works for one UserControl, but not the other. I've checked all everything.

string moduleName = drRegionModules["ModuleName"].ToString();

var uc = new Control();
switch (moduleName)
{
    case "Contents":
        uc = LoadControl(string.Format("~/uc/uc{0}.ascx", moduleName)) as ucContents;
        break;
    case "Menu":
        uc = LoadControl(string.Format("~/uc/uc{0}.ascx", moduleName)) as ucMenu;
        break;
}

Comment: I forgot to mention that it recognizes ucMenu as class, but returns error for ucContents.